# When should we worry about the page speed

Tags: wordpress, performance, pagespeed

I have seen many popular websites. Their page speed even not more than 90. My website page speed is more than 80. My question is when actually we should worry about the speed. Because For some days i am trying to speed up my page. But I don't know what is happening. Sometimes it's more than 90 then again it down less than 90.
My website is built on WordPress. I use All the plugin one by one. Such as smush, auto optimize, and others.

Answer (score 0):

It is best if you (or your WordPress developer) can integrate certain features directly into your website, so that you can get rid of plugins that might slow down your website. If you didn’t know, plugins are notorious for injecting all manner of CSS and JavaScript code at the top of your pages. This can negatively affect your page load speed.